# Alternative to save-excursion that only saves/restores point?

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros

**Q:** is there an alternative to `save-excursion` that only saves/restores point?

When writing elisp functions, I often need to save point, do some stuff in the current buffer, and then restore point.  I had always used `save-excursion` for doing so, but the docstring notes that it will:

> Save point, mark, and current buffer; execute BODY; restore those things.
>   Executes BODY just like `progn`.
>   The values of point, mark and the current buffer are restored
>   even in case of abnormal exit (throw or error).
>   The state of activation of the mark is also restored.

Now: that seems like overkill if all I care about is point and I'm not touching (or otherwise don't care about) the mark and current buffer.  In the absence of something like `save-point`, I wrote the following macro:

```el
(defmacro save-point (&rest body)
  (cl-declare (debug t) (indent 0))
  (let ((orig (cl-gensym)))
    `(let ((,orig (point-marker)))
       (unwind-protect
           (progn ,@body)
         (goto-char ,orig)))))
```

`save-excursion` is written in C, so it wasn't a priori clear that this macro would be faster than the C code despite saving and restoring fewer objects.  And, in fact, it's about an order of magnitude slower:

```
(benchmark-run-compiled 1000
  (save-point t))                   ; => .0005ish

(benchmark-run-compiled 1000
  (save-excursion t))               ; => .00005ish
```

It currently looks like the macro is a fool's errand.  So:

- Does something like this `save-point` macro already exist?
- How could one streamline this macro to speed it up?
- Is there any way to make up the speed difference between the C code and the elisp code?

Comment: Have you run into a situation where save-excursion is noticeably slow? This seems like a lot of effort to optimize away a tiny fraction of a second. Not that your questions aren't generally interesting (+1), but the application seems a bit strained.

Comment: @Tyler: not yet, but I've always wondered about the extra overhead for functions that get invoked a lot (eg, something called in `post-self-insert-hook`).  It may turn out to be a red herring, so right now it's a curiosity question.

Comment: In Emacs 25, `save-excursion` no longer saves the mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always easily save and restore point yourself, using `let` and `unwind-protect`. And you can roll that into your own macro, if you like. But why bother?

There is a reason that these things are saved & restored together by `save-excursion`. Otherwise, you had better be sure about which buffer you want to restore the value of point for etc.

My advice: use `save-excursion`. My guess is that it really costs nothing more than what you would code yourself to save & restore just point, and in fact will be quite a bit faster because it is coded in C.

Even if `save-excursion` were coded in Lisp it would be just two more `let` bindings, one call to `current-buffer`, one more `setq` and a `set-buffer`.

Comment: The macro was an attempt to write a `let` + `unwind-protect` template, but it appears to be the case that "why bother?" is indeed the practical upshot.